# Data loss in simple TCP socket connection using DNS?

Tags: sockets, tcp, dns, routes, network-programming

I have a mobile communicating unit which uses mobile-internet 3G to communicate to my server.

Scenario 1: When I use IP address for creating TCP sockets and send data through it, 100% of data which is sent is received on the server.

Scenario 2: When I replace IP address with Domain name, sometimes the mobile unit is not able to even establish a connection and even when connected sometimes data being sent from the mobile unit is never received on the server.

I want to use domain name since they will make the setup more manageable, I have also tried implementing reliability by using acknowledgments but its too-much of overhead.

Question is how can I use domain name and keep my data intact, further I would seek some explanation on how simply changing fro IP address to domain name can create such kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between using an IP address and a hostname as the target is that in the second case the name needs to be resolved to the IP address first, using DNS. In some locations the DNS query will not return the real IP address. This is typically the case with capture portals in WLAN hotspots but can also be with other kinds of traffic interception. Because your application then connects to the wrong IP address the data will not reach your server but instead some other host.

> ..how can I use domain name and keep my data intact..

You probably need to add some kind of authentication to your application so that you can be sure that you are talking to the correct host before you send any sensitive data. This way you at least notice that you are connected to the wrong host.

Comment: let us say I implement the some kind of auth mechanism and most of the time I find out that my mobile unit is unable to connect to the correct server then how do I fix the issue of to finding the correct server next time ?

Comment: @anand: next time connect the the hostname again and hope that this time the connection is not intercepted and the DNS will return the real IP.